# Rendering multiple pandas html tables side-by-side

Tags: python, html, css, pandas

I have produced individual html tables showing work orders from multiple departments , and a running count rendered in the header of how many are orders are 'Completed' out of the 'Total' number of orders in that department. This all works fine, but **I cannot find a way, clever or otherwise, to render these tables side by side on an html page**. I can't have the tables on top of one another because the page will be appear static on a large monitor through a raspberry pi, so scrolling isn't an option.

```
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')   # FOR TABLE <th>

table1 = CNC.to_html(classes='mystyle', na_rep='', index = False)
status1 = f"{C10} of {Total10} Completed"

html_string = f'''
<html>
  <head><title>HTML Pandas Dataframe with CSS</title></head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
  <body>
    <h1 style="border:2px solid DodgerBlue;font-size:35px;text-align:center"> C N C </h1>
    <h1 style="background-color:MediumSeaGreen;font-family:verdana;font-size:40px;text-align:center"> {status1} </h1>
    {table1}
    <script>setInterval(() => location.reload(), 60000);</script>
  </body>
</html>.
'''

with open("CNC.html", mode = 'w') as f:
     f.write(html_string.format(table=CNC.to_html(classes='mystyle', na_rep='', index = False)))
```

**CSS**

```
.mystyle {
    font-size: 15pt; 
    font-family: Arial;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
           
.mystyle td, th {
    padding: 10px;
}

.mystyle tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #E0E0E0;
}

.mystyle tr:hover {
    background: silver;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mystyle {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.mystyle {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Rendered CNC html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b1q3.jpg)

This obviously creates and renders only a single table on an html page

It would be great if there was some CSS magic I could use so that I could just apply that stylesheet to each department's html.